NO TOMCAT mapping when WAR file deployed
I am trying to deploy simpliest Spring Boot app TomCat server. Iam using TomCat manager to deploy. when i type any path iam getting 404 error. Everything works when running in Spring STS Boot run.
After deployment WAR file unpacked as supposed to.
If I map "/" to index.html it loads index page but when I type "/h1"  it goes to 404.
Using Maven built or Export file - same outcome
